# Why Regex CompileToAssembly giving slower performance than compiled regex and Interpreted Regex?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am using the following code to test CompileToAssembly performance against compiled regex but the results are not appropriate. Please let me know what am I missing. Thanks!!!

```
static readonly Regex regex = new Regex(@"(stats|pause\s?(all|\d+(\,\d+)*)|start\s?(all|\d+(\,\d+)*)|add\s?time\s?(all|\d+(\,\d+)*)(\s\d+)|c(?:hange)?\s?p(?:asskey)?|close)(.*)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
static readonly Regex reg = new Regex(@"(stats|pause\s?(all|\d+(\,\d+)*)|start\s?(all|\d+(\,\d+)*)|add\s?time\s?(all|\d+(\,\d+)*)(\s\d+)|c(?:hange)?\s?p(?:asskey)?|close)(.*)");
static readonly Regex level4 = new DuplicatedString();

    static void Main()
    {
        const string str = "add time 243,3453,43543,543,534534,54534543,345345,4354354235,345435,34543534 6873brekgnfkjerkgiengklewrij";
        const int itr = 1000000;
        CompileToAssembly();
        Match match;
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < itr; i++)
        {
             match = regex.Match(str);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("RegexOptions.Compiled: {0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < itr; i++)
        {
            match = level4.Match(str);
        }
        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("CompiledToAssembly: {0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < itr; i++)
        {
            match = reg.Match(str);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Interpreted: {0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void CompileToAssembly()
    {
        RegexCompilationInfo expr;
        List<RegexCompilationInfo> compilationList = new List<RegexCompilationInfo>();

        // Define regular expression to detect duplicate words
        expr = new RegexCompilationInfo(@"(stats|pause\s?(all|\d+(\,\d+)*)|start\s?(all|\d+(\,\d+)*)|add\s?time\s?(all|\d+(\,\d+)*)(\s\d+)|c(?:hange)?\s?p(?:asskey)?|close)(.*)",
                   RegexOptions.Compiled,
                   "DuplicatedString",
                   "Utilities.RegularExpressions",
                   true);
        // Add info object to list of objects
        compilationList.Add(expr);

        // Apply AssemblyTitle attribute to the new assembly
        //
        // Define the parameter(s) of the AssemblyTitle attribute's constructor 
        Type[] parameters = { typeof(string) };
        // Define the assembly's title
        object[] paramValues = { "General-purpose library of compiled regular expressions" };
        // Get the ConstructorInfo object representing the attribute's constructor
        ConstructorInfo ctor = typeof(System.Reflection.AssemblyTitleAttribute).GetConstructor(parameters);
        // Create the CustomAttributeBuilder object array
        CustomAttributeBuilder[] attBuilder = { new CustomAttributeBuilder(ctor, paramValues) };

        // Generate assembly with compiled regular expressions
        RegexCompilationInfo[] compilationArray = new RegexCompilationInfo[compilationList.Count];
        AssemblyName assemName = new AssemblyName("RegexLib, Version=1.0.0.1001, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");
        compilationList.CopyTo(compilationArray);
        Regex.CompileToAssembly(compilationArray, assemName, attBuilder);
    }
```

following are the results:

```
RegexOptions.Compiled: 3908ms
CompiledToAssembly: 59349ms
Interpreted: 5653ms
```

Comment: I just ran the code myself.  Here are my results: `RegexOptions.Compiled: 8399ms`;
`CompiledToAssembly: 7806ms`;
`Interpreted: 10405ms`.  Just what I would expect.

Comment: Tried again in Visual Studio in debug mode, got roughly the same results.  You are calling `CompileToAssembly()` separately, then running with that part commented out, correct?

Comment: I tried running the exe now the results are better... Don't know why it was giving weird results when i tried it earlier. Neway still the results don't match with the theroy Following are the results for 10000000 iterations : RegexOption.Compiled: 34413msCompiledToAssembly: 37125 Interpreted: 47322 .... Why complied to assembly taking more time than compiled regex??

Comment: I hope you ran this without the line `CompileToAssembly();`, otherwise the assembly would be recreated and has to be jitted again once you call `DuplicatedString`. From [Best Practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg578045%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Interpreted) we learn that it is important that the assembly is _not_ dynamically loaded, but is linked statically with your project, i.e. by building it in a prebuild step.

Answer (score 6):

Your code has a problem: static field initializers will run *before* static methods run.  That means that `level4` has already been assigned before `Main()` runs.  This means that the object referred to by `level4` is *not* an instance of the class created in `CompileToAssembly()`.

Note that the example code for `Regex.CompileToAssembly` shows the compilation of the regex and its consumption in *two different programs.*  The actual regex you're timing as "CompiledToAssembly" could therefore be a different regex that you compiled in an earlier test.

Another factor to consider: the overhead of loading an assembly into memory and jitting it to machine code might be significant enough that you need more than 1,000,000 iterations to see a benefit.

Comment: The difference is 55s! This is not due to one-time loading overhead. See my answer.

Comment: @usr, sure, that's why I mentioned it as "another factor to consider".  The more important factor is that the OP's sample code *is not timing the intended regex.*

Comment: Already checked the timing for loading the assembly into the memory its negligible compared to the time taken for each match when compileToAssembly option is used. Also, tried creating the object inside main() no effect as such.

Comment: @user1322631 have you checked that `match = level4.Match(str)` yields the expected result?

Comment: Yes, the regex is same and give same results.

Comment: You're not comprehending phoog's answer properly. You're calling `level4.Match(str);` and `level4` is not a regular expression object, compiled to assembly or otherwise. Your `CompileToAssembly` function does not do anything to `level4`.

Comment: This is not the actual code I complied the regex into assembly before running the test just showed here how I compiled into assrembly . Actual code only have main() without ComplieToAssembly() Call. and level4 is a Regex Object as I have defined in the code. Let me know if I am not clear stuck with this problem for last one day. Help appritiated!!

Comment: This the code i am using just comment the line which is calling  CompileToAssembly(); ... Try building a assembly of compiled regex which i have created and use it in your program if you get  results which are comparable to compiled regex or for that matter of fact even close to interpreted please let me know!

Comment: its in the same folder as you project mine was created in <projectFolder>\bin\Release

Answer (score 4):

You are running under a debugger (Visual Studio). It will prevent JIT optimizations from happening when an assembly is loaded. Try running without debugger (ctrl-f5).

Comment: Not running without a debugger will not magically turn the `level4` string object into a compiled regex.

Comment: The Compilation to Assembly for the regex was done earlier.. shown here how I compiled it into an assembly. This is not the actual code.

Comment: I tried running the exe now the results are better... Don't know why it was giving weird results when i tried it earlier. Neway still the results don't match with the theroy Following are the results for 10000000 iterations : RegexOption.Compiled: 34413ms CompiledToAssembly: 37125 Interpreted: 47322 .... Why complied to assembly taking more time than compiled regex??