# C# Regex Object Compiled vs DLL Speed

Tags: c#, regex

I have an application which as part of its function checks thousands of pieces of text against regex IsMatch and then a different Match. I figured since I'm checking thousands of things using approximately 20 regex, I would put them in a .dll precompiled and that would be faster. However, after benchmarking, it looks like compiling them in the code takes slightly less time than using the .dll. The difference is slight (approximately 5.4 seconds vs 5.2 seconds). I timed each solution multiple times using PowerShell Measure-Command and averaged them, so the compile time should be included.

The objects are only created once either way, before the loop. I also set the regex cache to slightly above the number I'm using (I'm not clear if this matters if I only create the object once, I'm guessing not).

Here's the two versions of the .exe code. Obviously both versions wouldn't compile at the same time, use your imagination.

```
    LimitHiPattern rgx_limithi = new LimitHiPattern();
    Regex rgx_limithi = new Regex(@"LIMIT_HI", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);

    foreach (CSVline line in input_data)
    {
        if (rgx_limithi.IsMatch(line.Cat))
             //a regex match extract here with a different regex....
    }
```

And the DLL code looks like this.

```
     RegexCompilationInfo LimitHiPattern = new RegexCompilationInfo(@"LIMIT_HI", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase, "LimitHiPattern", "Utilities.RegularExpressions", true);
     RegexCompilationInfo[] regexes = { LimitHiPattern };
     AssemblyName assemName = new AssemblyName("RegexLib, Version=1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");
     Regex.CompileToAssembly(regexes, assemName);
```

Obviously there are other regex involved, I just gave one.

I understand the difference is slight. But even when I run it against a subset of data, so with a much faster overall execution where the compile time should be a more significant chunk, it's still faster to not do the .dll (0.62 versus 0.61 seconds).

Is this just the penalty of going to lookup the object in the .dll file instead of staying within my own exe code? Overall this doesn't matter much in the scheme of my program, I just like understanding things.

**EDIT:**

some (slightly) more complete code, maybe I'm doing something really stupid that's causing this (likely!). I've retested and currently the dll version (pre-compiled) is 4.72 seconds and the compiled version is 3.05 seconds, a considerable difference. This is timed using a release build and measure-command in powershell.

```
using Utilities.RegularExpressions; //in custom RegexLib.dll
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         TextCounter(dicText, input_data);
    }

    private static void TextCounter(Dictionary<string, AudAll> dic, List<CSVline> input_data)
    {
          Regex rgx_limithi = new Regex(@"LIMIT_HI", RegexOptions.Compiled);
          //LimitHiPattern rgx_limithi = new LimitHiPattern();
            foreach (CSVline line in input_data)
            {
                AudAll currentCount;
                Match match;
                string smatch;

                if (rgx_limithi.IsMatch(line.Cat))
                {
                    smatch = rgx_limitdmsx.Match(line.Text).Groups[1].Value;
                    if (dic.TryGetValue(smatch, out currentCount))
                    {
                        currentCount.Increment(line.Audible);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        currentCount = new AudAll();
                        currentCount.Increment(line.Audible);
                        dic.Add(smatch, currentCount);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Obviously some stuff isn't declared and classes aren't created and stuff, I'm trying not to put in 500 lines of code. Sorry if my formatting and stuff is a mess, I'm not very good at SO.

Comment: Well, sometimes 0,01s less or more can make the difference when running millions of operations per second in a high-demand solution

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I don't think there will be a difference in actually using the regex, so even if there were 1 billion strings to check it would still be ~0.2s faster

Comment: What would be better is to optimize the regex you have, sometimes a single char can make a whole difference

Comment: @AlexanderDerck I said that from a generic point of view. The OP talks about a 0,01s gain like a "small improvement" and it mightn't be that small at all depending on the case

Comment: @AlexanderDerck Actually, it appears there is a difference in actually using it. Both cases should take the same up front time, but the actual time is only 0.01 seconds against a subset and 0.2 seconds against a larger set. That seems to indicate the actual use takes longer as well.

Comment: @Thomas Well, yes, and I've done that too. But because I do X doesn't mean I can't do Y as well, or am at least not interested in why Y behaves like it does.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079233/why-regex-compiletoassembly-giving-slower-performance-than-compiled-regex-and-in)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I might have been running the powershell timer against a debug build, but that would be dumb and I think I'm smarter than that. However, I double checked, and got much better results that are at least somewhat consistent with what I would expect when timing a release build. I've fixed some regex, so don't compare these times to above. Now 4.7 seconds for dll, 4.16 for non-compiled, and 3 seconds for compiled. Still don't understand why dll is so much slower. Using Ctrl-F5 in VS I get 2.7 seconds for dll vs 1.2 seconds for compiled, for the regex portion of code.